# What happens when importing libraries?

Tags: dart

Here is a silly simple question that's been running on mind. Does importing a library copy code to the current file when compiling or just allows reference to the library code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's only referencing. Each library is treated as a unique set of declarations, identified by the URI used to specify the library. Every other library which imports a library will see the same declared or exported declarations. Those name of those declarations then become available in the importing library's import scope.

A `part` file, on the other hand, is included literally in the including library.